# What does the command "$()" do in UNIX?

Tags: shell, command, command-substitution

What does the command `$()` do in UNIX? Could someone explain what is the significance of `$` in the below examples;

```
$(echo var=10)
```

and

```
eval $(echo var=10)
```

Comment: It was discussed hundreds of times. Please read documentation. // http://mywiki.wooledge.org/CommandSubstitution ; http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_03 ; etc

Comment: In addition to @rush's comment, you can find out that it is called _command substitution_ by searching `man bash` for “$(”. (Depending on your man pager, you may need to write the search expression as “\$\\(”.)

Comment: +1 Although there may be lots of already available answers to this question, it's a good question for U&L particularly with `$()` in the title -- which I don't see in the "Related" sidebar, and that is what people will look for if they don't know it is about *command substitution*.  So thank you for asking that way!

Answer (score 4):

This isn't a command itself, rather this is an example of **command substitution**. It takes the value of what is in parentheses and uses it in context.

For example, I will frequently make a backup of a file before editing it. I'll use command substitution to add the date to the end of the filename in [ISO 8601](http://xkcd.com/1179/) format (for sorting.) Of course, I could just type the date, but this is great for scripts where the date may be different each time it runs.

```
$ cp -p /path/to/file /path/to/file.$(date +%F)
$ ls /path/to/file.*
/path/to/file.2013-09-10 /path/to/file
```

Comment: This `$(echo something)` was always written `\`echo something\`` before, and you easily overlook those backticks, especially on a cheap printer.

Comment: Not to mention the nightmare it creates for nesting!